# comma delimited data within an SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, automation

I have an sql file that reads in a load of data from a comma delimited file.
This is causing us problems as different environments have different paths and so our automatic database scripts fail to run randomly.

We have not thought of a clever way of getting the correct absolute path, and it is further complicated by the requirement of the .csv file to be visible to the sql server.

I would be perfectly happy with a 'data block' within the sql file, but I am not sure if this is possible, or how best to arrange it if it is.

Edit: This is SQL Server :)

Comment: Probably it will be better to use SQL CLR for parsing .csv files. T-SQL doesn't really fit well for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

1. Have a master table with the paths on all the servers.
2. Synchronize this table as necessary (say, copy it around every night).
3. Use BULK IMPORT.  Construct the command in dynamic SQL.
4. Execute the command